# Bing Translate Widget for multiple language on the same page

Tags: internationalization, translation, bing, bing-api

While my site is manually translated to dozens of languages, the forum entries in it obviously aren't. That's where [auto-translation can be useful](http://colnect.com/en/forum/viewtopic!f=46&t=35678). I've been using Google's Translate button but currently experiencing problems with it (in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533887/google-translate-button-producing-odd-results-on-some-pages)).

So I've decided to try [Bing Translate Widget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn341982.aspx) which doesn't seem to deliver as the auto-detect finds a single language on the page and translates only from it. So my [multi-language forum topic](http://colnect.com/en/forum/viewtopic!f=46&t=35678) doesn't get translated with it at all.

1/ Is there a quick way to make the widget be aware of different languages in the same page?
2/ Is there a way using Javascript to instruct it to translate  by  which will obviously produce better results?

Thanks